# Disable keyboard shortcuts in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, summer-17, keyboard

I have a lightning component that provides it's own hotkeys and those are now overlapping with the new LEX hotkeys released in Summer '17. So pressing 'e' pops open the LEX edit, when i'd like to do something else. Salesforce also kills all propigation so my listener doesn't even get a chance to react. I'd like to disable the LEX hotkeys or better yet find a way to avoid triggering them when my component isRendered().

This is a long shot - I've already dug through the javascript and am pretty sure it's impossible.

Comment: Can confirm its impossible from lightening components, you can do this from Chrome extension or Tampermonkey, this is not a salesforce solution though.

Answer (score 9):

Alright - Suuuuper hacky, but I found a way. There is some code in keyComboProcessor.js _isEditingText() that checks a few ways the user could be editing. If you match these with your focused element you can sneak around the handler.

```
_isEditingText:function(keyboardEvent) {
    var targetElmt = keyboardEvent.target;
    if(targetElmt.tagName === "INPUT") {
      return!!EDITING_INPUT_TYPES[targetElmt.type]
    }
    if(targetElmt.tagName === "TEXTAREA") {
      return true
    }
    if(targetElmt.tagName === "DIV" && targetElmt.className) {
      return targetElmt.className.indexOf("cke_editable") !== -1 || targetElmt.className.indexOf("ql-editor") !== -1
    }
    if(targetElmt.tagName === "A") {
      return targetElmt.className.indexOf("select") !== -1 || !!(targetElmt.getAttribute("role") && targetElmt.getAttribute("role").indexOf("menuitem") !== -1)
    }
    return false
  }
```

For me, I just focused a DIV with a tabindex and gave it the cke_editable class.

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks for finding this. I have a `div` with `contentEditable = true` and was having an issue with `e` and `/` firing Salesforce shortcuts. Adding `cke_editable` to the `div` stopped all Salesforce shortcuts

Comment: Hi, Where can I find this "keyComboProcessor.js" file to make changes ?

Comment: @sf_user This is a SF system file, you can't modify it. What wellmstein was referring to is that he looked inside the code of that file and he noticed that piece of code that gave him the idea. In other words you don't have to modify the file, what you need to do is add a class name of "cke_editable" to your div and it will bypass the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Could someone please elaborate with an example. I have an aura page with a div tag and child tags of lightning:layout, lightning:recordEditForm, lightning:textarea,  lightning:input. In chrome browser, i am able to find div tag with tabindex in the aura generated HTML as below-
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal-glass slds-backdrop fadein slds-backdrop--open " data-aura-rendered-by="1138:0" style="opacity: 0.8;"></div> . But we don't have control to edit this rendered html file. We can only change aura .cmp file. Tried <div class="cke_editable"> in the cmp file but no luck so far.

Comment: I had to add `cke_editable` the html generated by a 3rd party component. To achieve this I had to use `setTimeout` to delay looking for the element until the 3rd party component has finished its render