# LWC: Capture keyboard event before lightning keyboard shortcut logic

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

In my LWC I have an event listener for `keyup` on a `div` with `contenteditable`(not sure if this issue won't persist with an input field as well).

I have imported that LWC into a Custom Object's Lightning Page. The issue I am experiencing is that when the user presses one of the [Salesforce's Keyboard Shortcuts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accessibility_keyboard_shortcuts_lex.htm&type=5) Salesforce takes over the event. For instance if the user presses "e" and "edit" component pops up and it bypasses my code.

I tried adding `evt.stopPropagation();` but it seems that Salesforce picks up the event before my component and on top of that it appears that the event never reaches my component after Salesforce captures it.

Is there a way for my component to capture the event first?

If not is there a way to disable the keyboard shortcuts for a certain lightning page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after additional researching I found out that there's no way to turn off the Lightning Keyboard Shortcuts at this point in time. SF are saying that it's on the roadmap but not going to be delivered in the next 2-3 releases.

> This is not currently a priority for the next 2-3 releases but please
>   do comment and upvote.

[Reference Link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015CZJQA2)

Additionally it seems that this is a problem with the use of a `div` with a property of `contenteditable=true`.

Fortunately a good samaritan found out that if one was to add a `class` of `cke_editable` to the div it will bypass the Shortcut Event that salesforce has in place. This absolutely works for now and hopefully there will be a more robust way to disable the shortcuts in the future.

[Reference Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183771/disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-lightning-experience)

[Another Reference Link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CVc5QAG)